# Right/Left Outer Join in from() and many 'and' with four tables in JOOQ

Tags: java, sql, oracle, jooq

I am a noob in JOOQ and need help to translate SQL to JOOQ.
So I have this long SQL statement here:

Please see this pic for a better insight: [Outer Join](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5PKDJ.png)

[image]

```sql
SELECT SUM(DECODE(VVS.VVS_ZWS_ID, 47, DECK.DEC_BRUTTOPRAEMIE_100,               DECK.DEC_BRUTTOPRAEMIE_FOLGE))
            FROM deck, agd, vvs, agv
            WHERE vvs.vvs_ver_nummer = verNummer
            AND vvs.vvs_nummer = vvsNummer 
            AND agv.agv_code = vvs.vvs_agv_code
            AND deck.dec_ver_nummer = vvs.vvs_ver_nummer
            AND deck.dec_vvs_nummer = vvs.vvs_nummer
            AND deck.dec_tbl_code = 'KH'
            AND agd.agd_code(+) = deck.dec_agd_code
            AND (    NVL(agv.agv_aenderungstyp, 'NULL') IN ('4', '5')
            OR NVL(agd.agd_aenderungstyp, 'NULL') NOT IN ('4', '5');
```

and I have translated the SQL statement with this:

```java
create.select(sum(decode().when(vvs.VVS_ZWS_ID.eq(47),deck.DEC_BRUTTOPRAEMIE_100)
                                    .otherwise(deck.DEC_BRUTTOPRAEMIE_FOLGE)))
            .from(deck, vvs, agv)
            .rightOuterJoin(agd)
            .on(agd.AGD_CODE.eq(deck.DEC_AGD_CODE))
            .where(vvs.VVS_VER_NUMMER.eq(verNummer))
            .and(vvs.VVS_NUMMER.eq(vvsNummer))
            .and(agv.AGV_CODE.eq(vvs.VVS_AGV_CODE))
            .and(deck.DEC_VER_NUMMER.eq(vvs.VVS_VER_NUMMER))
            .and(deck.DEC_VVS_NUMMER.eq(vvs.VVS_NUMMER))
            .and(deck.DEC_TBL_CODE.eq("KH"))
            .and(nvl(agv.AGV_AENDERUNGSTYP, "NULL")
              .in("4", "5")
              .or(nvl(agd.AGD_AENDERUNGSTYP, "NULL")
              .notIn("4", "5")))
            .fetch();
```

My questions are:
1. In the SQL statement `from` I have four tables, which are `deck`, `agd`, `vvs` and `agv`.
`agd` table has to be joined with `deck`table on  `agd.agd_code(+) = deck.dec_agd_code`. Have I translated the sql correctly?

 
2. How should I do with `vvs`and `agv` as these tables come after the `agd` in the `from()`?

I have spent two days thinking of this and I can´t solve this problem.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### 1:1 translation of your original query

While I generally do not recommend using the deprecated Oracle-style outer join syntax, do note that jOOQ does support it through [`Field.plus()`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/Field.html#plus--), so you could write:

**SQL**

```
AND agd.agd_code(+) = deck.dec_agd_code
```

**jOOQ**

```
.and(agd.AGD_CODE.plus().eq(deck.DEC_AGD_CODE))
```

#### Don't mix table lists with ANSI join

Other than that, the problem is more simple to explain. You were mixing "classic" table lists (several tables in the `FROM` clause) with ANSI joins, which is always confusing. When you do that with jOOQ, jOOQ will append the ANSI join expression(s) to the last table of your table list. In your case, this resulted in the following `FROM` clause:

```sql
-- Parentheses added for illustration purposes
FROM deck, vvs, (agv RIGHT OUTER JOIN agd ON agd.AGD_CODE = deck.DEC_AGD_CODE)
```

What you probably want in this case is a `LEFT OUTER JOIN`, in case of which your query *might* become correct.

But it would still be confusing, so in any case, I strongly recommend you migrate your query to all ANSI join first:

**SQL**

```
SELECT SUM(DECODE(VVS.VVS_ZWS_ID, 
              47, DECK.DEC_BRUTTOPRAEMIE_100, 
              DECK.DEC_BRUTTOPRAEMIE_FOLGE))
FROM deck
JOIN vvs
  ON deck.dec_ver_nummer = vvs.vvs_ver_nummer
  AND deck.dec_vvs_nummer = vvs.vvs_nummer
JOIN agv
  ON agv.agv_code = vvs.vvs_agv_code
LEFT JOIN agd
  ON deck.dec_agd_code = agd.agd_code
WHERE vvs.vvs_ver_nummer = verNummer
  AND vvs.vvs_nummer = vvsNummer 
  AND deck.dec_tbl_code = 'KH'
  AND (    NVL(agv.agv_aenderungstyp, 'NULL') IN ('4', '5')
    OR NVL(agd.agd_aenderungstyp, 'NULL') NOT IN ('4', '5'));
```

**jOOQ**

```
create.select(sum(decode().when(vvs.VVS_ZWS_ID.eq(47),deck.DEC_BRUTTOPRAEMIE_100)
                                    .otherwise(deck.DEC_BRUTTOPRAEMIE_FOLGE)))
      .from(deck)
      .join(vvs)
        .on(deck.DEC_VER_NUMMER.eq(vvs.VVS_VER_NUMMER))
        .and(deck.DEC_VVS_NUMMER.eq(vvs.VVS_NUMMER))
      .join(agv)
        .on(agv.AGV_CODE.eq(vvs.VVS_AGV_CODE))
      .leftOuterJoin(agd)
        .on(agd.AGD_CODE.eq(deck.DEC_AGD_CODE))
      .where(vvs.VVS_VER_NUMMER.eq(verNummer))
      .and(vvs.VVS_NUMMER.eq(vvsNummer))
      .and(deck.DEC_TBL_CODE.eq("KH"))
      .and(nvl(agv.AGV_AENDERUNGSTYP, "NULL")
        .in("4", "5")
        .or(nvl(agd.AGD_AENDERUNGSTYP, "NULL")
        .notIn("4", "5")))
      .fetch();
```

Comment: Thanks. I've tested the new sql statement and the old confusing one, and they delivered same outcome. But after I've run the jOOQ code on the IDE, it delivered a less outcome. How can it be?

Comment: @Luky: Are you sure there were no typos? Specifically regarding `verNummer` and `vvsNummer` bind variables...

Comment: my bad, I've compared different data/content. They deliver the same results now. Thanks a million :)